# Over-the-Range microwave bolt not tightening

Tags: kitchens, installation

I've installed an LG above range microwave and everything was smooth, but it seems that one of the bolts which come down through the cabinet above the microwave won't tighten at all.

I think they're called "blind bolts". The leftmost bolt is tight, but the bolt on the right just keeps spinning and spinning.

I'm worried that the microwave is prone to falling (it's securely fixed to the wall and one of the bolts is tight), but also - I'm not even sure how to begin fixing this - do I need to take the microwave down and try to find the nut which is presumably lost somewhere inside the microwave hole?

Cheers.

Image for some clarity: https://imgur.com/a/F8tpkZP

Comment: If it's a new microwave and the internal threads or nut are not functioning, you call up LG for warranty coverage, rather than voiding warranty by opening the thing up.

Comment: imgur link is 404

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact sorry, forgot to mark as public.

I ended up pulling the unit off the wall and looks like the guy I had helping me drilled down through the cabinet into the case of the microwave and we didn't notice. The nut for the blind bolt was knocked loose. Since there was already a hole drilled into the case, I figured the warranty was voided, so I pulled the case off and there it was.
I taped the bolt to the top of the case to hold it in place and it's now screwing in nicely.
Now I have to worry about the piece of aluminum tape that I used to hold the nut to the case

Comment: To the OP: you can answer your own question. (And for what it’s worth, I doubt that the foil tape will cause any issues. That stuff tends to stay stuck.)

Comment: If "the guy I had helping me" was any sort of paid installer (from the store you purchased from), contact the store, tell them what happened, and get them to get you an undamaged microwave and a competent installer. If he was your next door neighbor, brother (in-law), or other, well... you've made the most of the situation. I do wonder, though, why you were drilling with the microwave in place instead of marking hole locations, moving the _brand new thing_ then drilling. I'd be concerned about where in the microwave sawdust & metal shavings are...

Comment: @FreeMan he was a paid contractor who had installed the rest of the kitchen, told us to call him back if we wanted the microwave done, so it was sort of pro-bono that he was kind enough to do. Unfortunately I had to step out, we had drilled the holes from the template and I helped him hang the thing. But maybe in the interim he realized the hole was off and rather than drilling a new one he drilled through the microwave instead. I'm not really sure, to be honest. Visual inspection after we got the cover off confirmed no metal or wood debris.